# How does execve run commands?

Tags: c, shell, unix, command-line, execve

I attempted to use execve to run the command: `ls -l /tmp`, I'm familiar with the system call usage but I do not know how it runs commands.

I've tried this and i keep getting errors

```
char *argv[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};

int exec;

exec = execve("/tmp", argv, NULL);
printf("%d\n", exec);
return (0);
```

Comment: Never describe a problem merely as “i keep getting errors.” Always show the exact text of an error message. Also, when asking questions about programs not working, include a [mre] in the question, including an exact copy of the observed output, a sample of the desired output, and, for programs that take input, an exact copy of the input needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you checked the good old manpage? This [one](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) contains an usage example (close to the end of the page) and explicitely says *On success, execve() does not return...*

Comment: Providing an empty environment is not a particularly good idea.  You should use `execv()` unless you are specifically setting a minimal environment.  Or pass `environ` as the third argument — and there (still) isn't a header the declares `environ` so you have to write `extern char **environ;`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I found an empty environment to be very passable for toy examples such as this one. I guess that falls under one step at a time.

Comment: The reason you're getting errors you don't understand is you need to call `perror()`. Then you will get messages you have a ghost of a chance of doing something with.

Comment: @Joshua: As soon as the executed command needs environment variables such a `PATH` or `HOME`, things are likely to go doolally if you don't provide a sane environment.  See POSIX on [Environment Variables](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html).

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to `execve` is the path to the program to execute.<sup>[1]</sup>

```c
char *argv[] = { "ls", "-l", "/tmp", NULL };
execve( "/usr/bin/ls", argv, NULL );
```

Note that we had to provide the full path to the binary. To avoid this by searching the PATH when needed, we can use one of the "p" variants instead.

```c
char *argv[] = { "ls", "-l", "/tmp", NULL };
execvpe( argv[0], argv, NULL );         # execvpe is a GNU extension.
```

---

Passing `NULL` for the `envp` parameter is not standard. On Linux, it causes the new program to have an empty environment, which is very unlikely to be what's desired here. Instead, use

```c
char *argv[] = { "ls", "-l", "/tmp", NULL };
execvp( argv[0], argv );
```

---

Finally, the purpose of `exec*` is to change the program the current process executes. As such, it only returns on error, and it always returns `-1` on error. It's not useful to print this. To print the error message, one can use `perror`.

---

1. To set the path to use as the current work directory, use `chdir` before `exec*`.

Comment: Note that `execvpe()` is not part of POSIX.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler wtf? Thanks, adjusted.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use `execve` correctly. The first argument has to be the executable path.

So your code should be

```c
int  main(void) {
    char *argv[] = {"ls", "-l", "/tmp", NULL};

    execve("/bin/ls", argv, NULL); 
    // Or  "/usr/bin/ls", depending where  
    //    is stored 'ls' on your system

    // On success theses lines are not reached
    perror("execve failed");

    return 0;
}
```

Note that (from man execve):

> RETURN VALUE
> On success, execve() does not return, on error -1 is returned,
> and errno is set to indicate the error.

If the `execve` call is a success, your program will be replaced by the launched one (`ls` here), so the two last lines won't be executed

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `execve` must be the path to the program to execute:

```
exec = execve("/bin/ls", argv, NULL);
```

The second argument, `argv`, must be a list of all the arguments:

```
char *argv[] = {"ls", "-l", "/tmp", NULL};
```